# How to access upper scope value in python3?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, scope

In JavaScript this code returns 4:

```js
let x = 3;

let foo = () => {
  console.log(x);
}

let bar = () => {
  x = 4;
  foo();
}

bar();
```

But same code in Python3 returns 3:

```
x = 3

def foo():
  print(x)

def bar():
  x = 4
  foo()

bar()
```

https://repl.it/@brachkow/python3scope

Why and how it works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign to the global `x`, you'll need to declare `global x` in the `bar` function.

Comment: I don't want to assign global x because i don't want to overwrite top scope x. I want to overwrite x at bar() scope.

Comment: @brachkoff _"i don't want to overwrite top scope x"_ - But that's what the JavaScript part does.

Answer (score 1):

If a variable name which is defined in the global scope and also used in a local scope of the function, two things happen:

- You are making a read operation (Example: Simply printing it), then the value that variable reference is the same as the global object

```
x = 3

def foo():
  print(x)

foo()

# Here the x in the global scope and foo's scope both point to the same int object
```

- You are making a write operation (Example: Assigning a value to the variable), then a new object is created with it reference in the function's local scope. This no longer points to the global object

```
x = 3

def bar():
  x = 4

bar()

# Here the x in the global scope and bar's scope points to two different int objects
```

However, if you want to use a variable from a global scope and want to make write operations on it inside a local scope, you need to declare it as `global`

```
x = 3

def bar():
  global x
  x = 4

bar()

# Both x points to the same int object
```

Answer (score 0):

use global keyword

```
x = 3
def foo:
    global x
    x = 4
    print(x)
foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very clear that, the program, the machine is working in the mapping

```
bar()

# in bar function you have x, but python takes it as a private x, not the global one
def bar():
  x = 4
  foo()

# Now when you call foo(), it will take the global x = 3 
# into consideration, and not the private variable [Basic Access Modal]
def foo():
   print(x)

# Hence OUTPUT
# >>> 3
```

Now, if you want to print `4`, not `3`, which is global one, **you need to pass the private value inside the foo(), and make foo() accept an argument**

```
def bar():
  x = 4
  foo(x)

def foo(args):
   print(args)

# OUTPUT
# >>> 4
```

**OR**

> Use `global` inside your `bar()`, so that machine will understand that `x` inside in bar, is global x, not private

```
def bar():
  # here machine understands that this is global variabl
  # not the private one
  global x = 4
  foo()
```